# Android http response String split

Tags: android, string, http, split

I am making an Android app that searches for the prize bonds on a link on the Internet. I am using http request. All is working well, the problem is with the response string I am getting.

There are two type of results I get.

```
["000896","Third","Rs,93,00","55","Thu, Aug 1st 2013","City"]
```

This comes when there is a draw.

```
[" \t\t\t\t\t\t2)",null,null,null,null,null]
```

This comes when there is no draw.

What I want is to print each word of the string when it hits a draw. I am able to split the first one but when the second result comes, I get exception.

What method should I use so I can handle both the results.

Comment: Can you print log so that it would be easy for me to answer?

Comment: plz share your logcat so that I can see the exception.

Comment: please share logcat and method you are using to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if(myString.charAt(0) == '/'){
   //call second split method here
}
else{
//call draw split method
}
```

Or Maybe

```
 if(myString.startsWith("/")){
   //call second split method here
}
else{
//call draw split method
}
```